# Ubuntu server commands run through python give different response than when run through terminal

Tags: python, ubuntu, server

Running `echo $[100-$vmstat|tail -1|awk '{print $15}')]` returns my cpu usage as a percentage, when run in terminal. Running the same command in a python script,

```
f=os.popen('echo $[100-$vmstat|tail -1|awk \'{print $15}\')]')
cpu_usage=f.read()
print("cpu usage is: ", cpu_usage)
```

returns `(cpu usage is: ', <built-in method read of file object at 0x4343468f>)`, so for some reason it's returning a pointer instead of actual output.

Comment: Most likely you're not actually ***calling*** the read method as you say ( `f.read()`), but forgot the parentheses (`f.read`).

Comment: @LukasGraf is correct. This is why you are supposed to post your code, not post a comment about your code with some excerpts. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @doogabides exactly. And actually *copy & paste* from exactly that example, not write some new code in the question that may or may not do the same thing as the MCVE.

Comment: The issue with copy/pasting is that it's on a remote ubuntu server that doesn't like scp at all. The f.read without () was the problem.. god i miss actual IDE's.

Comment: @user409212 in such cases it helps to try and reproduce the problem locally (only works if you also got some flavour of Linux on your local box of course). And/or use `git`. Anyway, glad you were able to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the git tip, lukas. I think that will work well to allow me to get this code where i need it